# Feature Columns Embedding lookup

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have been working with the datasets and feature_columns in tensorflow(https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/introducing-tensorflow-feature-columns.html). I see they have categorical features and a way to create embedding features from categorical features. But when working on nlp tasks, how do we create a single embedding lookup?

For eg: Consider text classification task. Every data point would have a lot of textual columns but they would not be separate categories. How do we create and use a single embedding lookup for all these columns?

Below is an example of how I am currently using the embedding features. I am building a categorical feature for each column and using that for creating embedding. The problem would be that the embeddings for same word could be different for different columns.

```
def create_embedding_features(key, vocab_list=None, embedding_size=20):
    cat_feature = \
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
            key=key,
            vocabulary_list = vocab_list
            )
    embedding_feature = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
            categorical_column = cat_feature,
            dimension = embedding_size
        )
    return embedding_feature

le_features_embd = [create_embedding_features(f, vocab_list=vocab_list)
                     for f in feature_keys]
```

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/embedding_column

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was not able to figure out how to perform classification on text data with estimators. Could you please point me to a working example? Note: I have modified the question, to show how I am currently using the embedding features for text data.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have some misunderstanding. For text classification task, if your input is a piece of text (a sentence), you should treat the entire sentence as a single feature column. Thus every data point has only a single textual column **NOT** a lot of columns. The value in this column is usually a combined embedding of all the tokens. That's the way we convert a var-length sparse feature (unknown number of text tokens) into one dense feature (e.g., a fixed 256 dimensional float vector).

Let's start with a `_CategoricalColumn`.

```
cat_column_with_vocab = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    key='my-text',
    vocabulary_list=vocab_list)
```

Note if your vocabulary is huge, your should use `categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file`.

We create an embedding column by using an initializer to read from a checkpoint (if we have pre-trained embedding) or randomize.

```
embedding_initializer = None
if has_pretrained_embedding:     
  embedding_initializer=tf.contrib.framework.load_embedding_initializer(
        ckpt_path=xxxx)
else:
  embedding_initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-1.0, 1.0)
embed_column = embedding_column(
    categorical_column=cat_column_with_vocab,
    dimension=256,   ## this is your pre-trained embedding dimension
    initializer=embedding_initializer,
    trainable=False)
```

Suppose you have another dense feature `price`:

```
price_column = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('price')
```

Create your feature columns

```
columns = [embed_column, price_column]
```

Build the model:

```
features = tf.parse_example(..., 
    features=make_parse_example_spec(columns))
dense_tensor = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, columns)
for units in [128, 64, 32]:
  dense_tensor = tf.layers.dense(dense_tensor, units, tf.nn.relu)
prediction = tf.layers.dense(dense_tensor, 1)
```

By the way, for `tf.parse_example` to work, this assumes your input data is `tf.Example` like this (text protobuf):

```
features {
  feature {
    key: "price"
    value { float_list {
      value: 29.0
    }}
  }
  feature {
    key: "my-text"
    value { bytes_list {
      value: "this"
      value: "product"
      value: "is"
      value: "for sale"
      value: "within"
      value: "us"
    }}
  }
}
```

That is, I assume you have two feature types, one is the product price, and the other is the text description of the product. Your vocabulary list would be a superset of

```
["this", "product", "is", "for sale", "within", "us"].
```

Comment: Do you know if this works like you say if I'm just reading in from csv files via dataset api. So if I pass in a string feature like "this is a comment" then it will split out the words when looking to the vocabulary file as opposed to looking for the single 'word' "this is a comment". I don't see anything in the docs to suggest this so maybe I've been overthinking it.

Comment: Ps this is a question I just asked but your answer suggests I'm overthinking it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49861235/1919374

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the weights directly to the "embedding_column" layer, but it is expecting callable object.

Best way is to create an initializer class and pass it to the embedding_column like this

```
import tensorflow as tf

class embedding_initialize(tf.keras.initializers.Initializer):
  def __call__(self, shape, dtype=None, **kwargs):
    return tf.compat.v1.Variable(initial_value=[[1, 2], [2,3],[3,4]], dtype = dtype)


one_hot_layer = tf.feature_column.sequence_categorical_column_with_identity('text', num_buckets=3)
text_embedding = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(one_hot_layer,
                                      dimension=2, 
                                      initializer = embedding_initialize())
columns = [text_embedding]

features = {'text': tf.sparse.from_dense([[1, 2], [2, 1]])}

sequence_input_layer = tf.keras.experimental.SequenceFeatures(columns)
sequence_input, sequence_length = sequence_input_layer(features, training=True)
```